# Sql/php - insert data to a table with foreign keys

Tags: php, sql

How do you code in PHP to insert data into a table that has two foreign keys and these foreign keys are the primary key of different tables.

This is a many-to-many relationship so I am making a new table. I want to populate this table.

I searched a lot these past days on how to get the primary key of a row on the left table and right table to combine it in the middle table. But it all doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Can you post your database schema and what data you want to insert?

Comment: Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In addition to @Halcyon request, can you tell us what you've tried and why it hasn't worked?

Comment: My goal is to get the primary key of a row i just inserted with data in the first table. And also get the primary key of a row i just inserted with data in the second table. My third table is a relational table with first table's pk and the second table's pk as its primary key. This is a many to many relationship table.

Comment: You should use `mysqli_insert_id()` or `PDO::lastInsertId()` (depending on your mysql access method) after each insert, keep each into its own variable, then use those as your FKs when inserting into the 3rd table.

Comment: What does mysqli_insert_id() returns? A string or int ? My primary keys are both int. I tried to convert the result to int using (int)$var but still doesnt work.

Comment: It will return int.  Have a look at the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Thanks man. it worked now.

Comment: I just created my account here minutes ago. How can I rate you or like your comment?

Comment: Great - I just posted as answer - you can mark it as the answer by clicking the check icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `mysqli_insert_id()` after each insert, keep each into its own variable, then use those as your FKs when inserting into the 3rd table.

It will return int. Have a look at the doc: [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)